# Discord.py not responding to word commands

Tags: python, discord.py

When I run it , it have no errors and the statues change background task is running, but the word commands are not working. How to solve it??
The problem started when I regenerate a token

```
import discord, random
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

word_commands = [
    "we love you metallic",
    "daddy metallic!!!!",
    "metallic are you my dad",
    "metallic you are a fine species of a man!!!!",
    "everyone likes you metallic"
]

status = cycle(['your mom', 'your sister', "your grandma", "your step sis"])


@tasks.loop(seconds=3)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print("i am ready daddy metallic")


@client.command()
async def daddy_metallic(meta):
    await meta.send(random.choice(word_commands))


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'pong!Your latency is {round(client.latency*1000)}ms')
    print("sent")


@client.command()
async def eightball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = [
        "it is certain",
        "It is decidedly so",
        "without a doubt",
        "Yes - definitely",
        "you may rely on it",
        "As i see it, yes",
        "Most likely",
        "signs point to yes",
        "replay hazy , try again",
        "Ask again later",
        "better not tell you now",
        "cannot predict now",
        "concentrate and ask again",
        "don't count on it",
        'my reply is no',
        "my source say no",
        "very doubtful"
    ]
    await ctx.send(f'question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')


@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=10):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)


@client.command()
async def selfie(ctx):
    await ctx.send("https://imgur.com/a/C66kzi8")


client.run("token")
```

is it problem for my code or do i need to change anything from the discord developer portal

Comment: new `token` can't change how code works - if you only not use old `token` in code.

Comment: After copying all the code and testing it I could not reproduce the problem. Did you restart your bot after updating the token?

Comment: code works for me with my token. Did you use new token in `run(...)`?

Comment: yes i did use the new token and the bot runs with no error , now i think this is so permission thing in the discord developer portal stoping the word commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the prefix to `!`, but you're attempting to use `.` as the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gkLZ.png)

as you can see the background task of status changing is running but word commands not working